# How do i use Permissions for Android in Capacitor 4 project

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

i am trying to use Push Notifications with FCM and i don't know how to implement permissions in Android version to show the message dialog if the user wants to Allow Notifications on not in his/her device

service.ts

```
async registerFCM() {

await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', notification => {
    console.log('Push notification received: ', notification);
  });

  await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', notification => {
    console.log('Push notification action performed', notification.actionId, notification.inputValue);
  });
  

  PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(async result => {
    if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'android') {
            await PushNotifications.register()
            PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async ({ value }) => {
                console.log(value);

                this.submitFCM(value);
            });
          }
          else{
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        await PushNotifications.register();

        // Get FCM token instead the APN one returned by Capacitor
        FCM.getToken()
            .then((r) => {
                console.log(`Token: ${r.token}`)

                this.submitFCM(r.token);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
    } else {
        // Show some error
    }
});


async submitFCM(token) {
    console.log('token', token);// that's why the livereload is good, because you don't need to build again to see

    let url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'registerFCM'; // we need to create this function
    let data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
        api_signature: this.api_signature,
        registrationId: token,
        app_version: this.appData.APP_VERSION,

        device: {
            platform: this.device.platform,
            uuid: this.device.uuid,
            cordova: this.device.cordova,
            model: this.device.model,
            manufacturer: this.device.manufacturer,
            version: this.device.version,
        }
    });

    this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options })
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Push has been registered', data);
    })
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>


    <activity
    android:Permissions
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name="com.myproject.mobile.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
   </application>

<!-- Permissions -->

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

PHP FUNCTION

```
  function registerFCM()
{
    //print_r('goes into fcm');
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = $_POST;
    $response['success'] = true; // 1
    //print_r($data);
    $userDetails = getUserBySignature();
    $uid = $userDetails->uid;

    $fcm = array(
        'id_user' => $uid,
        //so with the new capacitor fcm i have a problem about storing the token
        //if i do it like  'register_id' =>  $data['registrationId']['token'],  stores the token because it returns the $data['registrationId'] as an array so you have to declare the ['token'] in order to store it in fcm table
        //also it doesnt store any device info
        'register_id' =>  $data['registrationId'],
        'platform' => $data['device']['platform'],
        'version' => $data['device']['version'],
        'uuid' => $data['device']['uuid'],
        'model' => $data['device']['model'],
        'manufacturer' => $data['device']['manufacturer'],
        'app_version' => $data['app_version'],
        'added_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );

    $db = getDB();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO fcm(id_user, register_id, platform, version, uuid, model, manufacturer, app_version, added_at) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql)->execute(array_values($fcm));

   $push['message'] = 'Hello'; 
    //$devices = $data['registrationId']['token'];
    $devices = $data['registrationId'];
    pushNotification($push, $devices);

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Do i add them in ><uses-permission? How do i do that for Push Notifications and Uploading Video and Audio files?

I tried to use the permissions but i can't. I am expecting to use the Permissions dialog for Android

Since i have PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(async result => { it should do the job right? But it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

The notifications permission is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

It only works on Android 13 devices, before that version notifications just worked and didn't prompt.

Capacitor plugins are not updated yet for prompting that permission as would be required when targeting SDK 33 (Capacitor targets SDK 32 at the moment).
But if you test on an Android 13 devices, the app will prompt for the permission on app startup if you are targeting SDK 32.

Comment: Isnt there a legal issue to ask for confirmation or not? Plus the it doesn't send the notification. I only get the notification if i send them from Firebase messaging

Comment: I don't think there are any legal issues, it's how Android works and has always worked. I don't understand the other part of your comment. You say you only get the notification if you send it from Firebase messaging. How else are you sending them that aren't working?

Comment: I updated to show you my PHP function. I should get a   $push['message'] = 'Hello'; everytime the user logs in

Comment: It does so in iOS version